# System.Configuration.Cast failing for objects without default constructor

Tags: c#, configuration, console

Am doing the following:

```
var temp = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Cast<KeyValueConfigurationElement>();
```

The above line throws an error saying it is unable to cast. The reason I probably see is that the class KeyValueConfigurationElement has only one constructor which is parametrized. There is no default constructor.

Can you please help to get around this?

Thanks
 Nishant

Answer (score 0):

Do the conversion explicitly

```
var temp = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings
    .Cast<object>()
    .Select((a, i) => new KeyValueConfigurationElement(
                              ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetKey(i),
                              a.ToString()));
```

`AppSettings` is a `NameValueCollection` which implements the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface. Therefore the `.Cast<object>()` is required in order to convert it to `IENumerable<T>` for the successive LINQ-Select.

Comment: I don't see Select method for the AppSettings

Comment: KeyValueConfigurationElement is a .NET class and parametrized constructor takes two strings (key and value)

Comment: I added a `.Cast<object>()` before the `Select` meanwhile.

Comment: I changed my example to make it work with the two parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an extension method to convert the values.

```
public static class NameValueCollectionExtensions
{
    public static KeyValueConfigurationCollection CastToConfigurationCollection(this NameValueCollection settings)
    {
        var collection = new KeyValueConfigurationCollection();

        for (int i = 0; i < settings.Count; i++)
        {
            var keyValue = new KeyValueConfigurationElement(settings.Keys[i], settings[i]);
            collection.Add(keyValue);
        }

        return collection;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var configurationCollection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.CastToConfigurationCollection();
```